# How to run single application in permissive mode and remaing all in enforcement mode for SEAndroid?

Tags: security, android, selinux

I want to allow single application to run in **permissive** and keep enforcing mode for all other applications in SEAndroid. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

we can run selected applications as permissive mode by adding the below line.

**permissive ;**

this process will only work on user debug compilation not on userbuild. So mostly we can follow this procedure for testing the feature in userdebug enforcement mode.